# Manual Numbered Pagination isn't working in wordpress template file

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have this code which works, showing "Older Entries" and "Newer Entries". However, I wanted to edit this code to show the "1", "2", "3", and so on without left/right arrows or Prev/Nex text. Therefore, I did research and was confused. I can understand what the tutorials such as [Wordpress Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination) (Numbered pagination is at bottom), [How To Add Pagination To Your WordPress Theme](http://www.wpexplorer.com/pagination-wordpress-theme/), and [Paginate Links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links), but they didn't say anything about where to put the code in. Only the second tutorial explained in full what I need to do but even so, that way wasn't working...

My code that works:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=9&posts_per_page=9&paged=' . $paged ); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
// the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
?>

<div class="proyectpost">
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <div class="innerpost">

             <div class="postthumbnail">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),'full' );
     echo '<img src="' . $image_src[0]  . '" width="100%"  />';
    } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="posttitle">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            </div><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="postsubtitle">
        <div class="datepanel">

        </div>
        </div>

</div>
</article><!-- #post-## --> 

</div>


<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php

// next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
?>

<?php 
// clean up after the query and pagination
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>

<?php else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The second tutorial said to add this code to the functions.php:

```
// Numbered Pagination
if ( !function_exists( 'wpex_pagination' ) ) {

    function wpex_pagination() {

        $prev_arrow = is_rtl() ? '&rarr;' : '&larr;';
        $next_arrow = is_rtl() ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;';

        global $wp_query;
        $total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
        if( $total > 1 )  {
             if( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
                 $current_page = 1;
             if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
                 $format = 'page/%#%/';
             } else {
                 $format = '&paged=%#%';
             }
            echo paginate_links(array(
                'base'          => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'format'        => $format,
                'current'       => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'total'         => $total,
                'mid_size'      => 3,
                'type'          => 'list',
                'prev_text'     => $prev_arrow,
                'next_text'     => $next_arrow,
             ) );
        }
    }

}
```

and to replace the default pagination with this code

```
<?php wpex_pagination(); ?>
```

How do I get it to work to display the numbered pagination in my wordpress template php file?

Comment: You just need to update the theme template file with the final part of your tutorial - even if it doesn't already exist to replace, you need to have `<?php wpex_pagination(); ?>` which will output the pagination.

Comment: Where do I put it? I used this '<?php wpex_pagination(); ?>' to replace '<?php next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); ?>' but it's not showing any results.

Comment: Based on what you have in your question, that should output the pagination. Make sure you are doing it on the right template file.

Comment: The template I use is template-proyectos.php. It's a template page.

Comment: A single page won't be paginated, you have to use it on archive or category pages.

Comment: I kinda doesn't understand. The code I have right now with "Older Entries" and "New Entries" works on my template page and therefore, the numbered pagination should work also...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93759/discussion-between-kristina-bressler-and-doublesharp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching a bit further, I found some clues which gave me inspiration to figure out where to put the right code so that I can get numbered pagination.

You use this code:

```
<?php
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

to replace:

```
<?php

// next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
?>
```

I think what makes me confused was when I was researching, some said to add some code in the functions.php while others said to use other code in certain places. Therefore, when I was reading [paginate links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links), this page wasn't clear on whether or not this new code above should be added to functions.php or to replace "prev/next" links.

Anyway, it works now! :)